# 3tb external hard disk on 32 bit system

Tags: disk

i have a 3tb hard disk with an external docking station that i can *not* use on my (old 265 mb) windows xp pc, because the pc is only 32 bit.  I plan to use a usb2 flash drive to boot into linux (e.g. Lubuntu, Elementary, or Mint).

Although the pc is 32 bit, I am wondering whether I can access (cleanly mount) the entire 3tb hard disk from with linux.  Are there linux utilities that work around the hardware's 32 bit limitation?  I'm asssuming that since the hardware is 32 bit, the linux version that I install on my flash drive must also be 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

The bit size of a processor has no connection with the maximum disk size that the machine can support. The reason you couldn't use your 3TB hard disk with your older PC is not because of a limitation in Windows XP, but because of a limitation with some of its hardware, probably with the disk controller. Each generation of disk controller has a maximum size for one reason or another — 512MB, 8GB, 2TB, etc.

Any halfway reasonable OS, even Windows, will support disks of any size that you can find on the market, provided that the hardware supports it. A limitation could come from the OS supporting the hardware only in some compatibility mode with a smaller maximum size, but in any case, it won't be an intrinsic limitation of the operating system or the CPU.

Comment: interesting.  i thought that 32 bit windows on a 64 bit pc could not address hard disks > 2 tb.  anyway, just to verify, based on gilles response, it is pointless to pursue "visualization" software within linux because i will still be bound by my old disk controller., right?

Comment: typo - previous comment - meant virtualization software, not visualization software

Comment: @user2661923 You can use virtualization software. It won't help you make a disk controller work (generally speaking, most hardware won't work any better with an OS that's running in a VM, and often can only be operated by the host anyway), but there are many other uses for virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

Having a 32-bit processor does not limit the size of the hard disk it can use, only of the amount of RAM it can (easily) address.

There have been limits in older IDE standards & controllers that prevent the use of larger hard drives. It's possible you'll hit that on an old machine, if this is an IDE disk connected via an IDE port.